# Php issue uploading two pdfs

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I'm having an issue with a form uploading two files. It works when I upload a PDF file using one file upload field, it also works if I upload two txt files using two fileupload fields. But if I try to upload two pdf files using two fileupload fields at one time I get a 500 error. The error within the error_log is permissions denied. I don't get these errors on two text files or one pdf file only when two pdf files.

Here's the post data.

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymCHfTtKQAJOYkMDB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contact_attachment"; filename="pdf-sample.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundarymCHfTtKQAJOYkMDB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contact_attachment2"; filename="pdf-sample2.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundarymCHfTtKQAJOYkMDB--
```

I have a working version of this locally and the codebase is the same. Could any php/server setting be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with apache and nginx users.